Duplicate expiration column in the couchbase schema
I got one issue on the Firebase crash-analytics where it showing the duplicate column name "expiration" this is document expiration time that is set at the time of the document save, as per the exception it throw exception at the time of the collection create.
In my code i check if the collection is already exist then use that collection, but i am not going to create the same collection again still getting the below exception
Caused by com.couchbase.lite.LiteCoreException: duplicate column name: expiration -- ALTER TABLE "kv_.\Events\Logs\Scope.\Event\Logs\Collection" ADD COLUMN expiration INTEGER; CREATE INDEX "kv_.\Events\Logs\Scope.\Event\Logs\Collection_expiration" ON "kv_.\Events\Logs\Scope.\Event\Logs\Collection" (expiration) WHERE expiration not null
at com.couchbase.lite.internal.core.impl.NativeC4Collection.createCollection(NativeC4Collection.java)
at com.couchbase.lite.internal.core.impl.NativeC4Collection.nCreateCollection(NativeC4Collection.java)
at com.couchbase.lite.internal.core.C4Collection.create(C4Collection.java:6)
at com.couchbase.lite.internal.core.C4Collection.create(C4Collection.java:2)
at com.couchbase.lite.internal.core.C4Database.addCollection(C4Database.java)
at com.couchbase.lite.AbstractDatabase.addC4Collection(AbstractDatabase.java:9)
at com.couchbase.lite.Collection.createCollection(Collection.java:2)
at com.couchbase.lite.AbstractDatabase.createCollection(AbstractDatabase.java:16)
at ma.dista.repository.storage.CouchbaseStorage.create(CouchbaseStorage.java:33)
at ma.dista.repository.MetaLayer.create(MetaLayer.java:42)
at ma.dista.repository.repositories.EventLoggerRepository.(EventLoggerRepository.java:45)
at ma.dista.repository.repositories.EventLoggerRepository$Companion.getInstance(EventLoggerRepository.java:2)
at ma.dista.repository.RepositoryProvider.getEventLoggerRepository(RepositoryProvider.java:2)
at ma.dista.activities.newClientDiscovery.ClientDiscoveryActivity$invokeClientDiscoveryLoadEvent$1.invokeSuspend(ClientDiscoveryActivity.java:12)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(BaseContinuationImpl.java:11)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.java:88)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.java:12)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(TaskImpl.java:2)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.java:14)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.java:28)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.java)
I want to find the actual cause of this issue without checking the that expiration column exist or not because i did't create the same collection again

Would you clear up some confusion? You mention Firebase, but all the code mentions Couchbase. Are you using them in conjunction somehow?

You haven't included any information about what version of CBL you are using or on what kind of device the issue occurred.

FWIW, @MichaelReiche, that is LiteCore adding the column, not the OP.

This is probably a data race in the way we handle the creation of the expiration column.
I have created https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/CBL-6131 to track the issue.
EDITED:
The ticket is now here:
https://jira.issues.couchbase.com/browse/CBL-6131
